# Loop through all Elements in Batch File after calling a VBs File

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, vbscript

So for reasons too long to explain I need to use a batch file to access information from a database. It isn't an ideal method, but it's the only one I could get working.

Here is the code that I am having some issues with:

```
    FOR /F %%i in (C:\Users\c1921\my_Data\mytestUnits.txt) DO (
    set "$Unit=%%i"
    echo The unit is :!$Unit!
    echo the token is still:%$token%

    curl -H "Authorization: auth_token %$token%" https://ads-dev.examplewebpage.com/apiv1/dsns/!$Unit!/properties.xml>C:\Users\c1921\my_Data\XMLFile.xml

    start C:\Users\c1921\my_Data\curltest.vbs

    echo pause after checking all the properties of a unit

    pause

      )
```

The problem is I have four test units in mytestUnits.txt and it will print the token and unit for each one but only run this line once:

```
    start C:\Users\cm\my_Data\curltest.vbs
```

I've tried using `goto:next` but that hasn't helped either. I also understand that `XMLDOM` (which I have written in curltest.vbs) doesn't have a close or delete method so I was thinking maybe that's the problem?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,

DM

**Edit:**

I added `echo pause after checking all the properties of a unit` to see when it reaches this point and this is only executed for the last item in the loop. I tried calling a new batch file with this information, but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without `start`

```
FOR /F %%i in (C:\Users\c1921\my_Data\mytestUnits.txt) DO (
set "$Unit=%%i"
echo The unit is :!$Unit!
echo the token is still:%$token%

curl -H "Authorization: auth_token %$token%" https://ads-dev.examplewebpage.com/apiv1/dsns/!$Unit!/properties.xml>C:\Users\c1921\my_Data\XMLFile.xml

C:\Users\c1921\my_Data\curltest.vbs

echo pause after checking all the properties of a unit

pause

  )
```

Comment: Another option would be using `start /wait`. You may also want to run the VBScript with `cscript.exe` instead of the default `wscript.exe` in a batch script.

Comment: I don't know why `ENDDO` worked for me it must have been a strange fluke. Anyway I tried as suggested without the `start` and it worked well. I'm going to use this since I assume this is the correct way of doing it. Why did `start` affect the loop in the first place?